# forcing users to follow others before continuing like in twitter

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on local microblogging platform and i will love to implement making members to follow a certain number of other members in the community (lets say 5) during signup thereby disabling the submit button until they follow the required number of members.

I am currently able to call a list of members and allow the new user follow or unfollow the members but cant seem to figure out how to force them to follow the number of members before they continue.

below is the sript am using to handle the follow and unfollow:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("btn.red").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).text("Unfollow");
    },function()
    {
        $(this).text("Following");
    });
 });

 //Perform the Following and Unfollowing work
function follow_or_unfollow(id,action)
{
    var dataString = "username=<?php echo $username;?>&id=" + id;
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "follow.php",  
        data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            if ( action == "following" )
            {
                $("#following"+id).hide();
                $("#loading"+id).html('<img src="assets/img/coming.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
            }
            else if ( action == "follow" )
            {
                $("#follow"+id).hide();
                $("#loading"+id).html('<img src="assets/img/coming.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
            }
            else { }
        },  
        success: function(response)
        {
            if ( action == "following" ){
                $("#loading"+id).html('');
                $("#follow"+id).show();

            }
            else if ( action == "follow" ){
                $("#loading"+id).html('');
                $("#following"+id).show();
            }
            else { }
        }
    }); 
}
```

will appreciate any help possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just thought I'd note that coercing *"likes"* and *"follows"* will likely break the terms of service and all the major platforms are wise to it.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be:

In the `follow.php` script:

After doing the necessary steps to follow someone, check if the user has followed the required number of users, if that's the case echo a "OK", otherwise echo a "KO".

In the javascript script:

This will be captured in the `response` variable in you javascript callback:

```
success: function(response)
{
     if(response=='OK'){
          // do something to enable the user to continue. Like enable the continue button.
     }
```